# spring boot mongodb @dbref cascade not working

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I am struggling with Spring Boot MongoDB cascade operations on referenced objects. Below are MongoDB document schema classes.

**== Post**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection="Post") // (1)
public class Post {

    @Id
    private String _id;

    @Indexed(unique = true) 
    private Long id; 

    private String title;

    private String body;

    private Date createdDate;

    @DBRef(db = "User", lazy = true) 
    private User user;

    @DBRef(db = "Tag", lazy = true) 
    private Collection<Tag> tags;
```

**== User**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection="User") // (1)
public class User {

    @Id //(2)
    private String _id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Indexed(unique=true)  // (3) 
    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String email;

    private String fullname;

    private String role;
}
```

**== Tag**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection="Tag")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    private String _id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private Long mid;

    private String body;

    private Date createdDate;

    @DBRef(db = "User", lazy = true) 
    private User user;
}
```

But @DBRef annotation does not work at all. It throws the following exception.

```
2019-03-01 14:54:10.411 ERROR 5756 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Cannot create a reference to an object with a NULL id.] with root cause

org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Cannot create a reference to an object with a NULL id.
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.createDBRef(MappingMongoConverter.java:975) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:597) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
```

When the json file is imported into MongoDB schema, the above error is shown.  I found some reference [site](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/spring-data-mongodb-cascade-save-on-dbref-objects.html) with googling which said to generate new event source using CascadingMongoEventListener class and user-defined @CascadeSave annotation. But I think there are another solutions with some cascade annotations. Any idea,please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Mongo` doesn't support the relationship between `documents`. Due to this cascade operation doesn't support in spring data mongo. you can do it in two manners.

1) Make your own cascade handler(best way to do is to use `spring event` publisher) But it can also be done using custom handler without spring event [see here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/spring-data-mongodb-cascade-save-on-dbref-objects.html).
2) Make an explicit call to referenced DB for operation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Then I want to know how to divide documents into module documents(for example, $ref annotation). If you have any reference site, then kindly inform me. Thanks!

Comment: updated my answer and also shared one link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommand the [spring-boot-up-data-mongodb](https://github.com/wnameless/spring-boot-up-data-mongodb) library. It works well with Spring Boot and provides Cascade, Annotation Event and Projection features to Spring MongoDB.

BTW, I am the author of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [RelMongo](https://github.com/kaiso/relmongo) which is a framework built on top of Spring Data and which make possible cascading, fetching.. and even lookups which are not possible with DBRefs